# xpath following-sibling and grouping like elements in a table

Tags: python-2.7, xpath

I have the following html from this [page](http://www.tspc.oregon.gov/lookup_application/LDisplay_Individual.asp?id=535454R3L38).

```html
<tbody><tr>
<td align="center" class="column_heading" width="200" title="The following are the Endorsements for the above license.">Endorsements</td><td align="center" class="column_heading" width="150" title="See Authorization Level Codes with their description at the bottom of the page.">Authorization Level(s) *</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#8AFF8A" class="section_detail">Health Education</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" class="section_detail">HS</td></tr><tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#8AFF8A" class="section_detail">Physical Education</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" class="section_detail">ML/HS
</td></tr></tbody>

<tbody><tr>
<td align="center" class="column_heading" width="200" title="The following are the Endorsements for the above license.">Endorsements</td><td align="center" class="column_heading" width="150" title="See Authorization Level Codes with their description at the bottom of the page.">Authorization Level(s) *</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center" bgcolor="#8AFF8A" class="section_detail">School Counselor</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" class="section_detail">ML/HS C
</td></tr></tbody>
```

I want to put the information under the first `Endorsements` and `Authorizations` into a list all zipped together and be able to distinguish it from the second table.

In a list it would look like this:
`['Health Education', 'HS', Physical Education', 'ML/HS\r'], ['School Counselor', 'ML/HS C\r']`.

What I'm getting now is this:
`['Health Education', 'HS'], ['Physical Education', 'ML/HS\r'], ['School Counselor', 'ML/HS C\r']`.

The short version of my code is:

```
test2 = tree.xpath(".//tr[td = 'Endorsements']/following-sibling::tr")
endorse1.append(test2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go is by the `td` background colors, try this snipped out, when you print, it should return the info that you want in a form of tuple.

```
everything=[]
for tr in tree.xpath("//tr[td[@class='section_detail']]"):
    row={}
    row['endorsement']=tr.xpath("td[@bgcolor='#8AFF8A']")
    row['auth']=tr.xpath("td[@bgcolor='#FFFFCC']")
    everything.append(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to group result per table/tbody, so get list of `tbody` first, then for each `tbody` find the target `td` text, for example :

```
>>> tables = tree.xpath("//tbody[tr/td = 'Endorsements']")
>>> result = [t.xpath("tr[td = 'Endorsements']/following-sibling::tr/td/text()") \
...             for t in tables]
... 
>>> print result
[['Health Education', 'HS', 'Physical Education', 'ML/HS'], ['School Counselor', 'ML/HS C']]
```